# Three objects on a Minkowski diagram?

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

On a standard two axis Minkowski diagram, is it possible to show three objects A, B and C, that aren't moving in a co-linear way? In the diagrams I have seen there are either only two objects, or if more than two then they are co-linear e.g. twins problem, although we have A. Earth, B. Ross-248 (other start and end points are available) and C. a spacecraft, they are all co-linear. In the event that we wanted to show on the diagram another path, is that possible, or do we then need (at least) two space axes (three axes in total)? E.g. would the one-space-axis Minkowski diagram still "work" if an object travels past one of the end points rather than directly to it?

Simplest case I think is a right angle triangle ABC, with the right angle at B, and C travelling towards B (i.e. the point of closest approach to A). Is there a way that you can use a Minkowski diagram to show the distance of the object C from A?

EDIT: to clarify, I'm wondering is whether it would work if the space axis actually shows "distance from A" rather than position along the co-linear direction.

Comment: A plane contains infinitely many lines.  What would stop you from drawing more than two of them?  (Of course all your lines will have to be coplanar.)

Comment: FWIW, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aberration_(astronomy)#Relativistic_explanation has an important SR calculation that involves X & Y space components.

Comment: @PM2Ring nice to see that thanks, though no Minkowski diagram to go with it sadly

Comment: Admittedly, 3D Minkowski diagrams are pretty rare. It's not easy to draw them in such a way that they're helpful rather than confusing.

Comment: You could make a plot of distance vs time, but that would not be a Minkowski diagram.

Comment: Here is an example of what I think is a useful (2+1)-dimensional spacetime diagram: my visualization: Relativity-LightClock-MichelsonMorley-2018  https://www.geogebra.org/m/XFXzXGTq

Comment: If the 3D diagram is interactive, it can be easier to see what's going on. Here's an example (but it's not a SR diagram). https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVUEFugzAQvEfiDytyAclFgTSHVLLUS3tGas9BFizYrWEt26TJ7wsGNfQyXq93PDO7h1Lenapd9vEGmjqKdq9q8GhF7aNdgy1USU2aLI_3x-bcnDFmYDT5ytA05_jzgUGPTvJPOyIDMqJW_s5zFu0AGmG_1weD1hmsvboifxfaTS0xeqpG0wi_ttKXmQRQAgeLV9KjVzRUs9yxSZLbpXjK00vBILmxA8uz4pQ-FNeTwWI34H-rm3r1PEO6aHqJPU668ew5BtUG84CTLYi16qSPl0Fj6WvOQcM8vYkVSJv7yiXrJXVWGKnq9Ysyc5J-ktaK_m8ZQZ8HZBsN_iinqINWA4aFpr_HDZMv&lang=sage

Comment: Wow nice to see the animation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Minkowski spacetime diagram is a position-vs-time diagram, as one finds in a PHY 101 textbook. (What essentially makes the spacetime diagram different from the PHY101-diagram is how to interpret displacements in space and time along segments that are not horizontal or vertical in the diagram.)

To answer your question, general motions in 3D-space represented on
a position-vs-time diagram require a 4-dimensional "(3+1)-position-vs-time diagram". If the essence of the situation can be captured in a lower-dimensional diagram, we often do so by taking an appropriate slice of the full diagram. (Note: Position-vs-time is not the same as distance-vs-time... distance is a number, whereas position is generally 3-dimensional.)

So, for example, a planet in orbit requires at least a (2+1)-dimensional position-vs-time diagram.... 2 spatial dimensions to locate where on the plane of its orbit, and 1 time dimension to locate when.

Comment: If it plotted distance vs time instead of position vs time, would it still work, or would distance on the x-axis break it? For situations where one object doesn't go past another (or at least is not plotted that far into the future), I think the two are equivalent, but I am not sure. I apologise by the way for the basic nature of the question, and very much appreciate you all taking time to respond.

Comment: @Raffles Distance discards information that one would generally need to locate an object. Being a distance of "2 meters away" does not fully locate me... I could be at x=-2 m or y=2 m or (x=$-\sqrt{3}$ and z=1) or a whole sphere's worth of positions. Just plot positions (like a "number line" or "sea level", not distances)-vs-time.

Comment: true, but it does allow you to plot an object moving towards another object that goes past at some distance (i.e. never arrives at it)... however thanks to your answer I'm concluding that it doesn't do so in a helpful or useful way. Thanks